# Use Kerberos-ticket in C# client application

Tags: c#, webclient, kerberos, single-sign-on

I have a web-application where I'm automatically logged in with my Windows Credentials.
I now want to consume information from this web-application, in a c# windows application using my Windows Account. Therefore I need to be able to get the session-cookie from this web-site.
Here you can see a piece of my code, where I want to retrieve the cookie :

```
       string URLAuth = extractParameterFromProperties("relatieBeheer_login_url");
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
       // webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.DownloadData(URLAuth);
        //byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URLAuth, "POST", formData);
        string resultAuthTicket = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        if(resultAuthTicket.Contains("Verkeerde combinatie gebruikersnaam")){
            sessionCookie="NoSession";
        }else{
                WebHeaderCollection cookies = webClient.ResponseHeaders;
                sessionCookie = cookies[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];
        }
```

When I debug the application, I can see nothing is filled in the credentials :
Domain, Username & Password are empty.

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The ICredentials instance returned by DefaultCredentials cannot be used to view the user name, password, or domain of the current security context.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx

Comment: OK, but do you mean that DefaultCredentials should indeed send the Kerberos-ticket then??

Comment: @user1370849 I believe they should be sent with the authentication, however you are unable to see them in the variable due to security reasons.

Comment: Any way I can troubleshoot this. In wireshark I don't see any Kerberos ticket passing, while I can see it pass when I just USD à web browser